# How to isolate / remove 1 subsystem, jar in a multi-war ear deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly, war

Currently I'm testing multi-war modules inside an ear deployment.

Basically I have 2 wars that are dependent on: hibernate-validator which is further dependent on: javax.validation.api and contains ValidatorFactory. I think this also cause the activation of jca subsystem.

What I don't understand is why am I getting:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.naming.context.java.module.xxx-ear.cmp.ValidatorFactory is already registered"},
```

I understand that I have defined them on 2 separate wars but aren't they supposed to be isolated?

I also tried adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml in ear's meta-inf folder which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others 
        classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxx-api.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
        </exclusions>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jca" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </sub-deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="xxx-web.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I tried excluding the jar in deployment and sub-deployment - failed. I also tried excluding the whole subsystem in main deployment or sub-deployment also failed.

Any idea how to solve this kind of issue? What if I have another jar that the 2 wars will depend, then from this case I assume that I will also have a similar issue.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file? Your application should never include it's own Java EE API jars.

Comment: Could you share your POM files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on this one is not related to pom nor jboss-deployment-structure but rather on web.xml. I have accidentally set the same module name  on both war thus causing the name collision. The name is the same as the package name so the error got me confused. In case somebody encounter the same issue, check your web.xml first.